How can I get my form validation to work?
I'm trying to validate my form but when I press submit it's not working. I have the script from Just-Validate. I just don't see where I could have made a mistake

this is my js
import JustValidate from 'just-validate';

const validation = new JustValidate("#signup");

validation
    .addField("#name", [
        {
            rule: "required"
        }
    ]);

this is my signup form
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@exampledev/new.css@1/new.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.xz.style/serve/inter.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/just-validate@latest/dist/just-
                        validate.production.min.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validation.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>Signup</h1>
    
    <form action= "process-signup.php" method = "post" id="signup" novalidate>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
        </div>
        
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type = "email" id = "email" name = "email">
        </div>
        
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
        </div>
        
        <div>
            <label for="password_confirmation">Repeat password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation">
        </div>
        
        <button>Sign up</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        const validate = new window.JustValidate("#signup");
      </script>
    
</body>
</html>










this is what I'm hoping to get


Either put the code that calls new JustValidate in a top-level script in the HTML or in a .js file that you load from the server, not both. And if you have a <script> tag that loads just-validate.js, you don't need to import it as well.

You can only use import in a script if the <script> tag has type="module". Didn't you get an error in the console telling you that?

Just saying, you could also use this for simple validation.  Just add required at the end of your input tag to make it required. EXAMPLE:  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>

If using the defer attribute on the script element, make sure that you don't refer the JustValidate function before the DOM is loaded (defer on the <script> element).


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  const validation = new JustValidate("#signup");

  validation.addField("#name", [{
      rule: "required"
    }]);
});
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@exampledev/new.css@1/new.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.xz.style/serve/inter.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/just-validate@latest/dist/just-validate.production.min.js"
  defer></script>

<h1>Signup</h1>

<form action="process-signup.php" method="post" id="signup" novalidate>
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="password_confirmation">Repeat password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation">
  </div>

  <button>Sign up</button>
</form>



